# invoke rest api with array of string

Tags: java, json, rest

```
[
    ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
    ['a1','b1','c1','d1','e1','f1','g1'],
    ['a2','b2','c2','d2','e2','f2','g2'],
    ['a3','b3','c3','d3','e3','f3','g3']
]
```

I have above string, have converted to json object as:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("name", "a");
    json.put("country", "b");
    json.put("state", "c");
...
...

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
...
HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post);
```

This works fine for me.

My question is instead of above code, i,e creating json object and sending, can I directly pass the string to my rest component? If possible, what type of mime I need to select?
Requirement is pass the entire string and split in backend java component instead of split, convert to json then send to back end.

Answer (score 0):

The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json. The default encoding is UTF-8. (Source: RFC 4627).

Comment: my above code perfectly works fine with json. I want to call rest passing entire above string without converting to json.